ARIMAResult Apply method error message when forecasting on unseen data
I have fitted arima model for time period from 2010/01 through 2020/01. This model is fitted with order p=1, q=12 and have four exogenous variables which are binary indicator defined as follows:
exog_col_a = 1 if date > 2015/01 else 0
exog_col_b = 1 if date > 2018/06 else 0  
exog_col_c = 1 if date <= 2020/05 else 0 
exog_col_d = 1 if date <= 2019/08 else 0 

Model fitted as:
model = ARIMA(input, exog=df[['exog_col_a','exog_col_b', 'exog_col_c', 'exog_col_d']])
fit = model.fit()

Now, I have an unseen data starting 2024-01 to 2025-06 which i would like to forecast. My code to forecast is as follows:
 mod_results.apply(new_data, exog=new_data[['exog_col_a','exog_col_b', 'exog_col_c', 'exog_col_d']])

However, I get valuerror:
"A constant trend was included in the model specification, but the 'exog' data already contains a column of constants".
I am assuming, since my newdata exog columns are constant mostly 1 (for col_a and col_b) and 0 (col_c, col_d), it is causing this error. Is there a way to resolve this issue?
New Data has following columns:
Month (set of index), exog_col_a, exog_col_b, exog_col_c, exog_col_d
exog_col_a and col_b are 1 for all rows
exog_col_c and col_d are 0 for all rows
Link credit: I learnt about 'apply' from 'cfulton' comment in the question below:
Forecast with ARIMA model with python using unseen data instead of training data
